# userDefaults.registerDefaults change for Swift 2?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, swift2

Here is the full code I am using to save a high score:

In the game scene:

```
func atGameOver() {
     var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
            var highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
            if (score > highscore){
                defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore") }
            var showHighScore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore")
            let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            var totalScore = userDefaults.integerForKey("totalScoreKey")
            totalScore += self.score
            userDefaults.setInteger(totalScore, forKey: "totalScoreKey") 
    }
```

In the app delegate:

```
var totalScoreKey: Int = 0
 override init() {
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let defaultValues = [totalScoreKey: 0]
        userDefaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues) }
```

Since going for Swift 2 and xCode 7 I'm getting this error:

> "Cannot convert value of type '[Int : Int]'to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]'"

It's on the `userDefaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)` line. It worked for Swift 1.2 "illegal" or not and the app was released, how do I go about changing it for Swift 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `totalScoreKey` is an Int. That's illegal. (If you were doing this in Swift 1.2, that's no excuse; this was still wrong, and now what's happening is that you've been caught out.)

The key into NSUserDefaults must be a string. Rewrite this line:

```
var totalScoreKey: Int = 0
```

As this:

```
var totalScoreKey: String = "totalScoreKey"
```

That way, the key will match the key you are using here:

```
var totalScore = userDefaults.integerForKey("totalScoreKey")
```

The zero (`0`) you are trying to pass here needs to be the *value*, not the key; you are already passing that:

```
let defaultValues = [totalScoreKey: 0]
                                    ^ -- this is the zero value
```